# How to fix blank space on the bottom of lighting HDRs

Tags: rendering, add-on, light

I downloaded this an hour ago and cannot figure out for the life of my how to get rid of this gap. I would REALLY appreciate some help. The only way to hide it is to put the camera right on the ground and point it upward, but it looks terrible because the grass covers the entire camera. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: This "gap" is not a gap. The bottom of the HDR is black as ground lighting is minimal in real life, and it saves on memory tremendously. You will need to change the angle or add some horizon elements.

Comment: Adding some horizon elements would be a good idea. It's a bit hard to come across a field that's going to be that flat without something covering the sky a bit anyway.

Comment: Damn. That's a shame because I was going for a flat field with a slope that falls into the sky. You would think there would be a way to lower the sky down. I guess I just don't understand it. Even if I added trees the spaces between them would be black.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are seeing is blank space not stored in the HDR. Since the lighting received from the ground in real life is actually quite minimal, this information is not included in order to save memory. Usually you will have an environment providing those reflections in your scene instead.

To get around this issue, you can do a few things:

- Change the camera angle
- Rotate everything away from the horizon
- Add some horizon elements
- Use a different HDR

**Camera Angle:**
[image: Angle]

*Move the camera so that the black is no longer visible*

**Rotate Objects:**
[image: Rotation]

*Just rotate the whole scene so it is angling towards the camera*

**Horizon Elements:**
[image: Horizon]

*These could be mountains, trees, hills, etc.*

---

Now you mention that you do not like the camera angle when moved very low, and I understand that. Really your only option is to (if you have the purchased version) add a different HDR, or add some horizon elements like trees, mountains, etc. A scene that consists of just a house on a hill can be somewhat amateurish, as beginners do not like to add nature to their architecture renders.

Do a little more research, and you will find that almost all the powerful Arch Viz images are closer, and have convincing surrounding elements. I think that maybe this issue will help push you to explore more creative angles and environment choices. Such will only result in a more powerful result.

If you still want to use your original idea, I would recommend making whatever would be on the other side of the valley, or over the hill. Having some atmospheric fading distance wise will really help sell the effect, making it more believable that it is on a hilltop.

Comment: Incredible advice thank you. I am a beginner (couple months) and started to go the route of "basic" just as you were saying. You've helped me realize that and I'm now adding some hills using proportional editing on the subdivided plane. I'm going to add some big rocks on the hill and if I'm brave enough I'll try to make some trees. Thanks again for the great advice!

Comment: @JoshFiricano That is what we're here for :) Always glad to be a help